# How to get the name of the array in json data using ReactJs?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs

I have a JSON which comes back like this from a API call:

```
"free_seat_blocks": {
    "blocks_by_row": {
        "22": [
            [
                "2218"
            ]
        ],
        "23": [
            [
                "2315",
                "2316",
                "2317",
                "2318"
            ]
        ],
        "24": [
            [
                "2411",
                "2412",
                "2413",
                "2414",
                "2415",
                "2416",
                "2417",
                "2418"
            ]
        ]
    },
}
```

How can I access the name of the array (i.e 22, 23, etc) in `ReactJs`. I need to use the name of the array to display the seat Row in table format.

Update:

I want to get the values of the keys also and display them like below -

```
Row     Seat Number
22      2218
23      2315,2316,2317,2318
24      2411,2412,2413,2415,2416,2417,2418
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`blocks_by_row` is an `object` and you want to access the key names. There are multiple ways of doing the same.

If you just want to display the name (keys) of `blocks_by_keys` object, use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) on it, it will return an array of all the key names.

Like this:

```js
let data = {
  "free_seat_blocks": {
    "blocks_by_row": {
        "22": [
            [
                "2218"
            ]
        ],
        "23": [
            [
                "2315","2316","2317","2318"
            ]
        ],
        "24": [
            [
              "2411","2412","2413","2414","2415","2416","2417","2418"
            ]
        ]
    },
  }
}

var App = () => {
   return(
     <div>
         <table>
            <tr> 
                <td>Rows</td> 
                <td>Seat No</td> 
            </tr>
            {
               Object.entries(data.free_seat_blocks.blocks_by_row).map(([row, seats]) => <tr key={row}>
                   <td>{row}</td>
                   <td>{seats.join(',')}</td>
                </tr>)
            }
         </table>
     </div>
   )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, its working but I also wants to get the seat numbers. I have updated the question for same, can you please have look and advise the solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the key names of the `blocks_by_row` object.

```
const keys = Object.keys(free_seat_blocks.blocks_by_rows); // Will return an array ['22', '23', '24'];
```